# Issue with formatting of Dates in Momentjs

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs, moment-timezone

I need to check if a date is in between two dates or not in my codebase. I'm using [isAfter](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-after/) and [isBefore](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-before/). I can't use [isBetween](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/) coz I've 2.2 version of moment.

Anyways, so locally everything is working fine, but whenever I push it to production, it is not giving me correct results. So I've pasted the function below. Can anyone tell me the exact issue.

I'm even using UTC dates. I guess the issue is in time zone. MomentDate variable is still taking Eastern time zone.

```
// date is a JS Date(new Date())
// startdate and enddate is a string 'MM/DD/YYYY'
function isDateInBetween(date, startdate, enddate) {
  const momentDate = moment(date).utc(true); // js object
  const momentStartdate = moment(startdate, 'MM/DD/YYYY').utc(true); // string in 'MM/DD/YYYY format'
  const momentEnddate = moment(enddate, 'MM/DD/YYYY').utc(true); // string in 'MM/DD/YYYY format'

  console.log('date', momentDate);
  console.log('startdate', momentStartdate);
  console.log('enddate', momentEnddate);

  if (!date || !startdate || !enddate || !momentDate.isValid || !momentStartdate.isValid() || !momentEnddate.isValid()) return false;

  if (momentDate.isSame(momentStartdate, 'date') || momentDate.isSame(momentEnddate, 'date')) {
    return true;
  }
  else if (momentDate.isAfter(momentStartdate, 'date') && momentDate.isBefore(momentEnddate, 'date')) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: I guess I need to pass the date in 'MM/DD/YYYY' format. So will this work?
const date = new Date();
const newDate = new Date(date).getUTCDate();
const newMonth = new Date(date).getUTCMonth();
const newYear = new Date(date).getUTCFullYear();
const d = `${newMonth}/${newDate}/${newYear}`;
And pass this d a parameter to the function.

Comment: you don't need a huge library like `momentjs` for a simple dates comparison, it's a huge overkill, just convert to timestamp and use math to check if a date is before or after another

Comment: @vsync The library is already there.

Comment: You need to provide sample input, expected output and actual output so as to provide a minimal example that demonstrates the issue. As it stands, it's impossible to diagnose. If you want to compare dates without the time component, then any timezone will do as long as they all use the same one. One issue might be that you need to set the input date to `startOf('day')`, but without seeing an actual example it's impossible to know. AIUI, Moment's utc switch just changes output and calculations to UTC, it doesn't change the actual time value of the underlying Date.

Comment: hey, I actually resolved the issue. so what I did is first I extracted the utc date, month, and year. Then I formed a string and then did the comparisons(see my first comment).

Comment: I didn't exactly understand what the issue was, but it was related to the timezone, even after using UTC.